# NodeMailer, send specific number of emails

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I need help sending a specific number of emails with nodemailer, lets say i want to send 20 emails to a specific person.
This is my code.

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
  host: "smpt.gmail.com", //smtp server
  port: 587,
    pool: true,
  secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
  auth: {
    user: "testtest@gmail.com", // mail
    pass: "testtesttest" // password
  }
}));
transporter.close();


// setup email data with unicode symbols
let mailOptions = {
  from: '"Test Test" <testtest@gmail.com>', // sender address
  to: mailto, // list of receivers
  subject: args[1], // Subject line
  text: args[2] // 
};

async function sendMail() {
  let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  sending = true;
}

const SendingMessage = setInterval(() => {
  var mailto = args[0];
  mailOptions.subject = args[1];
  var mailtxt = args[2];

  sendMail();
}, 1500);
```

How do i make it send a message like "hey" to test@test.com 5 times only. because currently it just sends "hey" until i hit my smtp sending limit

Comment: First you need to decide for yourself what is this 20-30 emails that you are sending, then save it in an array. You will call `sendMail()` whenever you have a email to send.

Answer (score 0):

First create an array of mail content you want to send, for example;

```
const mails2send = [
{
 from: '..',
 to: '..',
 subject: '..'
 text: '..'
},
{
 from: '..',
 to: '..',
 subject: '..'
 text: '..'
},
{
 from: '..',
 to: '..',
 subject: '..'
 text: '..'
}
]
```

Modify the sendMail function to take in argument.

```
async function sendMail(mailOptions) {
  let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  sending = true;
  return sending;
}
```

then map through the `mails2send`

```
mails2send.forEach( item => sendMail(item ))
```

**Update** It appears you may be talking about your setInterval function

```
let counter = 0;

const SendingMessage = setInterval(() => {
  
  var mailto = args[0];
  mailOptions.subject = args[1];
  var mailtxt = args[2];
  sendMail();

  if (counter === 4) {
      return clearInterval(SendingMessage); //<-- clear the interval when reach 5.
  }
  counter++ //<-- counter increment.
  
}, 1500);
```

Comment: Alright thanks, but im still abit confused on where put the mails2send.forEach( item => sendMail(item ))

Comment: How do i make it send a message like "hey" to test@test.com 5 times only. because currently it just sends "hey" until i hit my smtp sending limit, i tried your code, doesnt work for me

Comment: what do u mean 5 times only, why would you send it 5 times and not only once? Do you mean your setInterval function? Updated the code to show how you can use `clearInterval`

Comment: Lets say i want to send hey to test@gmail.com 5 times so i do [ !send test@gmail.com hi hi  ] and it sends 5 emails to test@gmail.com with subject hi  and message hi.  like a prank to annoy a friend or something.

Comment: You do know non solicited emails may eventually not reach your friend's mailbox right? There are rules to sending emails in order for mail servers to not recognise it as a spam, or even ban your server

Answer (score 0):

Umm, maybe this is what you want ?
This will send mail to each of address 5 times and blocking / synchronously.

```js
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

function template(address) {
  return {
    from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>', // sender address
    to: address, // list of receivers
    subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
    text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
    html: "<b>Hello world?</b>", // html body
  };
}

async function main() {
  const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
    port: 587,
    auth: {
      user: "augustine.kozey54@ethereal.email",
      pass: "5Jq3GYxyTu51Pxx8Hr",
    },
  });

  const addresses = [
    "budi@mail.com",
    "ami@mail.com",
    "indah@mail.com",
    "july@mail.com",
    "meita@mail.com",
  ];

  /*
    Using for loop
  */
  //   const mailer = [];
  //   for (let i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
  //     for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  //       mailer.push(transport.sendMail(template(addresses[i])));
  //     }
  //   }

  /*
    Using for map
  */
  const mailer = addresses
    .map((address) => {
      return [...Array(5)].map((i) => transport.sendMail(template(address)));
    })
    .flatMap((array) => [...array]);

  return await Promise.all(mailer);
}

main()
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

Comment: Lets say i want to send hey to test@gmail.com 5 times so i do [ !send test@gmail.com hi hi  ] and it sends 5 emails to test@gmail.com with subject hi  and message hi.  5 emails saying "hi" to the 1 email address, not 5 different email addresses

Comment: hmmm, you can modify it guy, just change the template text, and change the addresses to test@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

function template(address) {
  return {
    from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>', // sender address
    to: address, // list of receivers
    subject: "Hi", // Subject line
    text: "Hi", // plain text body
    // html: "<b>Hello world?</b>", // html body
  };
}

async function main() {
  const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
    port: 587,
    auth: {
      user: "augustine.kozey54@ethereal.email",
      pass: "5Jq3GYxyTu51Pxx8Hr",
    },
  });

  const addresses = [
    "test@gmail.com"
  ];

  /*
    Using for loop
  */
  //   const mailer = [];
  //   for (let i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
  //     for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  //       mailer.push(transport.sendMail(template(addresses[i])));
  //     }
  //   }

  /*
    Using for map
  */
  const mailer = addresses
    .map((address) => {
      return [...Array(5)].map((i) => transport.sendMail(template(address)));
    })
    .flatMap((array) => [...array]);

  return await Promise.all(mailer);
}

main()
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((e) => console.error(e));
```